# Does AWS ELB connection draining apply when terminating an instance using the console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm trying to achieve zero-downtime deployments for my `AWS EC2 Auto-Scaling Group`.

Consider this scenario:

- I've got 3 instances in my ASG.
- I want to do a rolling release with a new version of my app.
- So I want to spawn 3 new instances, and then terminate the old ones.
- I've got connection draining enabled on my `ELB` with a reasonable timeout that should easily allow any current connections to any given instance enough time to finish.

My Question:

So if I go about terminating the "old" instances, will they drop connections, or does the ELB connection draining still apply?

What about with the CLI tooling?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application depends on connections getting drained then dont just terminate instances. For draining to work the instance need to be deregistered from the ELB. CLI, Console or API wont make a difference here.

Since you already use autoscaling you could set the custom termination policy [`OldestInstance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html), raise the desired number of instances in the group to 6, wait for new instances to become available, then reduce the desired instances to 3. Autoscaling will remove the oldest instances for you. If you need to change the launch configuration you can use the `OldestLaunchConfiguration` termination policy similarly.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the detailed answer @BretzL! I'll give it a go and post back here if I run into any issues.